# Adaptations to being able to program with right hand only?

Tags: linux, windows

Long story short, I was diagnosed with glioblastoma last August right before going off to Boise State to study computer science. I had surgery to remove one of the tumors and because of the surgery, I am paralyzed in my left arm. Hopefully, it's only temporary. I had to cancel the school year to do treatment but I am attending this fall. I still can't type with my left at the moment but we got speech to text software for some of my classes.

Except, my programming classes which I would find very difficult to succeed in with my left hand being the way it is right now.

I am wondering if anyone had a solution to this problem specifically software wise but would also love to hear about the hardware?

Also, it's not like I cant program, it's just extremely difficult and tedious with one hand.

moved to:https://superuser.com/questions/1311225/adaptations-to-being-able-to-program-with-right-hand-only?noredirect=1#comment1949694_1311225

I thought it would be more appropriate there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about typing are not really about programming.

Comment: Can't think of a way to help with software if you cannot use your left hand. May be this will help: https://www.enablemart.com/maltron-one-handed-keyboards-right-and-left-hand

Comment: Alternatively to a one handed keyboard and speech recognition would be handwriting recognition. A handwriting keyboard is built into Windows 10. If you get a tablet or 2-in-1 laptop, you can use handwriting to input text. https://www.howtogeek.com/297443/how-to-use-handwriting-input-on-windows-10/

Comment: This has [come up on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9340238), such as Tavis Rudd's presentation on [coding by voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI). Also see [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/222893/solutions-for-one-handed-typing-on-a-regular-keyboard)

Comment: Programming is a whole lot more than just pressing keys. I would venture to say you are a whole lot quicker coding with one hand, than I was coding with two when I begin learning to program in the mid 80s (at that time, there were no computers accept at the university -- and most people, me included, had never touched a keyboard before sitting down in a numerical methods class). The one-handed keyboard, speech and handwriting keyboard sound like you best choices at this point. (here's to hoping you won't need them)

Comment: I have been programming for years. So it's not like I'm starting from scratch.I have even done university work